# Vue app, Javascript, conditionally adding an Object to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, javascript-objects

I have a restaurant menu which is an array of objects each of which has the following properties:-

- name
- id - the id is autogenerated
- quantity
- options - which itself is an array that has two value pairs -size & price

Now, I want to allow the user to add items to the shopping cart after validating that the selected Item doesn't already exist in the cart, the problem I am facing is, each Item has an Id, but at the same time has two or more different sizes

Here is my code

```js
export default {
data(){
  return {
    cart: []
  }
}

//...
methods: {
    addItem(pizza, options){
      let selectedPizza= {
        id: pizza.id,
        name: pizza.name,
        size: options.size,
        price: options.price
        quantity: 1
      }
      
      if(this.cart.length > 0) {
        this.cart.forEach(item => {
          if(item.name === selectedPizza.name && item.size === selectedPizza.size && item.id === selectedPizza.id) {
            return item.quantity++
          } else {
            this.cart.push(selectedPizza)
          }
        })
      } else {
        this.cart.push(selectedPizza)
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

the code above works fine except when I try to add the same pizza with a different size, because the id, in this case, is repeated as each item has the an Id, not every pizza size has one, anyone can think of a workaround? 
thanks in advance..

Comment: What is the desired behavior, to have multiple sizes for one pizza ?

Comment: I am sorry your question is not clear enough to me, in the menu, each  Pizza has two sizes, so i want to allow the user to add not only different pizzas, but the same pizza with different size. for example he wants to have two margherita pizzas one large size and one small size..

Comment: so data structure issues don't belong to coding issues? would you please remove your negative rating if you can't help ?!

Answer (score 0):

This seems more of a data structure issue rather than a syntax or coding issue. In your case I'd add a duplicate pizza, one for each size. That way you can still increment the amount. IE:

- Pineapple Pizza (small) 1x
- Pineapple Pizza (large) 1x

  You'd have to restructure your data if you'd want to
- Pineapple Pizza 2x (small & large)

Your question doesn't really show what solution you want.

Comment: So your suggesting that, In the menu Items, I should have for example, pineapple Pizza (Large) as an Item, and another separate Pineapple (small) right? I know that it does make sense, but I think there should be a way to have the same pizza with different sizes and also allow me to have the desired functionallity.