# Vue.js, conditionally adding item to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, javascript-objects

I have a hardcoded menu Items in which I loop through to display its content in a table, then I have an add button for each item. 
what I want to do is to allow the user to add the selected item to his shopping cart which I initialize in my data function as an empty array, so first I want to validate that the selected Item doesn't exist in the user shopping cart, so if it doesn't exist, it will be added, if it does, I want to increase its quantity by one. 
please find my code to implement this functionality in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qzw1q0lj7w) in the root app.vue component, 
Please ask for any further clarification in a comment below - if needed. thanks

Comment: Please place your code in your question, using links to other pages will work right now, but won't in the future when someone else visits this question.

Comment: I did yesterdeay, and the question wasn't clear enough and nobody answered, find it here in [stackoverflow-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946848/vue-app-javascript-conditionally-adding-an-object-to-an-array?noredirect=1#comment92802056_52946848)

Comment: I would appreciate if you unrate the question if it were you who did

Comment: Then why did you think this would be clearer than your previous question?

Comment: because this is a vue app setup which is my case, and the viewer can run the code and get the result !! I am trying to rephrase the question so it could be clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in the forEach inside addItem function.Please find the updated code.

```
addItem(pizza, options) {
      let selectedPizza = {
        name: pizza.name,
        siza: options.size,
        price: options.price,
        quantity: 1,
        id: options.size === 'L' ? pizza.id.split('').reverse().join('') : pizza.id
      }

      if(this.cart.length > 0) {
        let exist = false;
        for(let index = 0; index < this.cart.length; index++) {
          let item = this.cart[index];
          if(item.id === selectedPizza.id && item.size === selectedPizza.size){
            item.quantity++;
            this.response ='Item already exist in the cart';
            exist = true;
            break;
          } 
        }
        if(!exist) {
            this.response = ''
            this.cart.push(selectedPizza)
        }
      } else {
        this.cart.push(selectedPizza)
        console.log('item is added to an empty cart')
      }
    }
```

You were adding pizzas into the cart multiple number of times inside forEach, if current iteration pizza is not equal to the selectedPizza.

Comment: hallelujah brother :D, thanks very much. that saved my day